# Multithreading: thread or process.h - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, process, beginthread, beginthreadex

I started studying multithreading. And I've found 2 ways to use it ic C++. First is by `thread`

```
#include <thread>
...
std::thread t(function);
<< some code>> 
t.join(); //(or detach)
```

And second is by `process`

```
#include <process.h>
...
_beginthreadex('bunch of parameters');
<< some code >>
_endthreadex()
```

So what, if anything, is the difference? And if there is a difference, when should one be used instead of the other?

Comment: Use `thread` for looped logic concurrency and `async` for task-based concurrency. `process.h` is non-standard. Not recommended for someone who is new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick with the first and standard way in C++ to create thread, i.e, using std::thread.

The second is Microsoft specific. I doubt that anyone would use it nowadays.
See this: https://www.quora.com/When-do-we-write-include-process-h/answer/Sergey-Zubkov-1

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

You missed one: [CreateThread()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) which is also Microsoft (WinAPI) specific and is found in many Windows programs.

> what, if anything, is the difference?

`_beginthreadex` and `CreateThread` are non-standard Microsoft/Windows specific functions.

`_beginthread` has support for starting a thread in [Managed Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/archive/blogs/brada/what-is-managed-code) which may be useful in a mixed environment.

`CreateThread` is the native WinAPI call to create a thread. It's *the* call you'll find in classic Windows programs. A thread handle returned by this call gives you the ability to control the thread in different ways, for example, by calling [SetThreadPriority()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadpriority) etc.

Using `<thread>` is the, since C++11, standard way to do threading. It has most of what you will ever need - but lacks some platform specific support for dealing with the threads. Yet, a thread created by the standard library can return the native thread handle to enable prioritization etc. by using platform specific calls with that handle.

> if there is a difference, when should one be used instead of the other?

Since you are learning threads and are not digging around in old code, you should definitely go with `<thread>`. It'll probably take a very long time before you feel the need to use native calls to fiddle with the threads in a platform specific way - and if you do, you can still get the native handle.

Using `<thread>` also makes your programs portable. In a Posix environment, the threading is usually done by Posix Threads (with a totally different API than the Windows API), yet by creating code that uses pure `<thread>` calls you make porting your program a non-issue. It just works.